# Video Attachment in a Card is not autoplaying

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

i'm posting a card with a video attached, this card is the second on in a bundle.
I can swear that some weeks ago the video was autoplaying when entering the card, not is not.

Is there a way to force/toggle to autoplay of an attached video?

KR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an enhancement made in the latest build to include user's response, there are cases where video could be an optional where it is played on-demand by user. (https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=115)

I have not yet tried to auto-play of attached video, i'll let you know, if i find a way.